# 100% height won't work

Tags: html, css, wordpress-theming

For some reason, the `.container` is only 100% of the browser window if I apply a border to it. it only  Here is the code, without the border:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display:block;

}
```

And the HTML is as simple as

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner_box">
        <div class="text_box">Project Three</div>
        <ul>
            <li>content</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Would anyone know why I would require a border on the .container to get it to be 100% height?

Comment: What's not working here? http://jsfiddle.net/mYNxx/

Comment: 100% we are not getting what you are saying

Comment: Its already working see here http://jsfiddle.net/JCtPk/

Comment: Haha love it VIVEk, I assume he means the border is being cut off as I have seen this so many times on here, the border is showing outside your height 100% and width 100% so will only be visible on top and left

Comment: Hmm, still not working here: http://herbert-theme.info/

Comment: Done, but still not 100%

Comment: @tmyie On your website, the first container has a height of 100%. However, the innerbox in the second container has a top margin of -300px, which causes it to overlap the first container by 300px!

Comment: Hmm, but I'm using that it center the `inner_box`. That's got a top:50% and margin-top: -300px?

Comment: You problem is in the context of a WordPress theme, which you did not mention earlier.  Your fiddle did not include enough code to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Do you have any idea of why being a WordPress affects this particular problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your container `position:relative` and make your inner box absolute centering with `margin: auto; position:absolute top:0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;`

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display:block;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;

}

.inner_box {
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px; 
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
    background-color: #f1f1ee;

}
```

Comment: I've copied and pasted but it seemed to break the page. I've now just removed the `margin-top`, but I required that to center the `.inner_box` within each `.container`

Comment: i have updated my code see now if its working or not, just replace this above two codes with the original one.

Comment: That does work! Could you the changes made?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the 100% height is working in your code. It is just that without border you can't see it. If you want to check it press F12 in Chrome and hover the html elements to see proper height and width of your html elements. If still there is an issue then consider applying 100% height to `.inner_box` class. It will make some change. BUT STILL YOU CANNOT SEE 100% height WITHOUT DEVELOPER TOOLS.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and checked in Chrome with developer tools. For me your .container is 100% height even without the border. 
With this code, you can see it's all right.

```
    background: red;
```

Add it to your container class and you'll see.

Comment: Here it is live, but not working: http://herbert-theme.info/

Answer (score 0):

.. because your container doesn't hold default margin of your inside elements as hx , p, etc...

Border will do the trick as padding.

You may then use :

```
.container {
   padding:1px;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   }
```